# No boot manager after new Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my C drive using the windows installer LTS. Windows 7 also resides on my C drive. The installation appears to have completed but I never did get the boot manager (GRUB) window at start-up. So my computer only boots to Windows 7. Also I no longer see my F8 or F12 boot options - not good! Thanks for any help in this!

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7 open an admin prompt and type:

```
bcdedit /enum all /v >bcd.txt
```

attach bcd.txt when posting back.

This will show all entries you have in Windows BCD (boot config data).

Wubi method of installation is using chainloading of Grub over Windows boot manager.
Ubuntu itself is placed in a virtual disk (a special file on disk).

You should have a

> boot sector loader

entry in BCD to chainload Grub.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down SHIFT and power on the machine - let go when you see the boot window. Does that work? If not, boot from the LiveCD and post results of the Boot Info Script:http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/.

Comment: Please note that if you do this - replace boot_info_script.sh in the command with bootinfoscript there have been changes.

Answer (score -1):

First of all there would be no GRUB for UBUNTU install using WUBI i.e Window Ubuntu Installer.

At booting process of win7 you will see option as other os beneath of Win7. Press down arrow key to select that beneath option and u will boot to UBUNTU.

Hope this is what you are looking for